# Real-time navigation for Web development

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

For an app I'm building, I need real-time navigation. I've chosen Google maps, but I'm noticing there's nothing on real-time navigation for websites.

What are my options? Am I better off going with another provider, like Bing or Mapquest?

Comment: 1) we can't recommend software/tools or other off-site resources (see [help/on-topic]) 2) what do you mean by "real-time navigation for websites"?

Comment: 1) Everything can be considered off-site. Despite that being your rule, the need for suggestions is intertwined in most questions. I'm not sure how to ask without asking for suggestions. My primary question is how to implement Google Maps API to get directions in real-time (based on current position in relation to destination). Secondary is to use an alternate service that allows for this. 2) My question is tagged with google maps. Real-time navigation, as in like using Google Maps on your phone with step-by-step real-time directions.

Comment: hey @TylerMontney does my answer helps in your quest for navigation.. if so please mark it as answer :) thx

Answer (score 1):

of course there is.

the real-time navigation is nothing more but capturing the current position of the user and displaying it or laying on top of the Google Map or other map.

you have to choose the technology on the server or back-end service to handle the capturing / storing positions in the database. I'm sure the server language or stack that you are using (node, php, asp..etc) has some libs for that already.. 
this is the Google page that uses cloud DB solution and native browser caps for capturing your position.. and this is the jsfiddle with example how to capture your current position... simple oneliner right :)

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
```

start from that and build it up gradually, good luck!

kres